# Неправильно работают функции сокращения дроби и подсчет цифр большего в дроби

Tags: c++, математика, struct, численные-методы, арифметика

Необходимо написать программу, которая высчитывает сумму ряда.

На вход дается количество элементов n суммы ряда.

Формула суммы ряда:
[image: Суммы ряда.]

**!!!НЕ ПОДКЛЮЧАТЬ БИБЛИОТЕКУ MATH!!!**

> Подсчет суммы ряда выполняется без ошибок, НО при использовании функций **cut_frac** и **line** знаменатель дроби обнуляется, а числитель считается некорректно. Весь мой код в конце.

**cut_frac (сокращение дроби)**

**line (подсчет количества цифр в наибольшем числе для вывода правильной длины дробной черты)**

*Необходимы функции:*

*• ввода элемента суммы n (с проверкой);*

*• сокращение дроби;*

*• сложение дробей (дробь-сумма должна быть несократимой, поэтому в теле функции сначала вычислить*
*новые числитель и знаменатель, а затем, найдя НОД, выполнить сокращение);*

*• Реализовать функцию, выводящую результат на экран в виде дроби ( знаменатель*
*числитель) с дробной чертой необходимой и достаточной длины.*

*• Вызывая функцию нахождения суммы дробей нужное количество раз, вывести промежуточные*
*результаты на экран, а результирующие данные – на экран и в файл.*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
//нельзя добавлять библиотеку cmath!!!

using namespace std;

//Написать программу по вычеслению суммы ряда. Вычисления суммы ряда происходят накопление. Следуйщий элемент суммы ряда прибавляется к предыдущим элементам.

//Структура Дробь
struct drob 
{

    int chis = 1; //Числитель (значение 2 элемента ряда)
    int znam = 6; // Знаменатель (значение 2 элемента ряда)
    int n = 1; // Количество элементов сумм ряда

    //Функция ввода кол. элементов суммы ряда
    int enter()
    {
        cin >> n;
        while (n <= 0) //Проверка на допустимость
        {
            cout << "Неверное значение! Введите заново." << endl;
            cin >> n;
        }

        cout << endl;
        return n;
    }

    //Первая сумма ряда
    void sum_frac1()
    {
        int stepchis = 2;//Значение числителя 2 элемента суммы ряда
        int stepznam = 12;//        и знаменателя
        int z = 6;

        //Для того чтобы посчитать сумму ряда мы к предыдущим элементам ряда прибавляем следующий элемент ряда.
        //То есть накоплением.
        while (n > 1)
        {
            chis = chis * stepznam + znam * stepchis;
            znam = znam * stepznam;
            stepchis += 1;
            z += 2;
            stepznam += z;
            n -= 1;
            cout << endl;
            display(); //Вывод дроби
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    //Вторая сумма ряда
    void sum_frac2()
    {
        int stepchis = 1;
        int stepznam = 3;

        while (n > 1)
        {
            chis = chis * stepznam + znam * stepchis;
            chis = znam * stepznam;
            stepznam += 1;
            n -= 1;
            cout << endl;
            display(); //Вывод дроби
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    //Вывод дроби
    int display()
    {
        int l = 4;

        //  l = line(chis,znam);        Не работает!
        //  cut_frac(chis,znam);        И это тоже

        ofstream file; //вывод конечного значения в файл
        if (chis != znam)
        {
            file.open("C:\\Users\\Максуд\\Documents\\02.04.2021\\2 semester\\Проект4\\array.txt");
            cout << chis << endl;
            file << chis << endl;
            while (l > 0)
            {
                cout << "-";
                file << "-";
                l -= 1;
            }
            cout << endl << znam;
            file << endl << znam;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << chis;
            file << chis;
        }
        file.close();
        return 0;
    }
    
private:

    //Сокращение дроби
    int cut_frac(int &chis, int &znam)
    {
        int nod = NOD();

        chis = chis / nod;
        znam = znam / nod;
        return chis;
        return znam;
    }

    //Наибольший Общий Делитель для сокращения
    int NOD()
    {
        while (chis > 0 && znam > 0)
        {
            if (chis > znam)
            {
                chis %= znam;
            }
            else
            {
                znam %= chis;
            }
        }

        return chis + znam;
    }

    //Функция подсчета цифр в числе для нужной длинны дробной черты
    int line()
    {
        int l = 0;
        if (chis > znam)
        {
            while (chis > 0)
            {
                l++;
                chis = chis / 10;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            while (znam > 0)
            {
                l++;
                znam = znam / 10;
            }
        }
        return l;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    int menu;
    cout << "Лабораторная №4\nВыполнил студент ДИНРб-11 Бикеев Максуд Рубинович" << endl;
    cout << "1. Ряд дробей\n2. Ряд последовательностей\n\nВведите номер: ";
    cin >> menu;

    switch (menu)
    {
    case 1:
        do
        {
            drob frac1;

            cout << "\nВведите кол-во n элементов ряда суммы: ";
            frac1.enter();
            frac1.sum_frac1();
            
            cout << "\nКонечный результат: " << endl;
            frac1.display();

            cout << "\n\nЕсли хотите выйти то введите 0, иначе другое число: ";
            cin >> menu;

        } while (menu != 0);

        break;

    case 2:
        do
        {
            drob frac2;

            cout << "\nВведите кол-во n элементов ряда суммы: ";
            frac2.enter();
            frac2.sum_frac2();

            cout << "\nКонечный результат: " << endl;
            frac2.display();

            cout << "\n\nЕсли хотите выйти то введите 0, иначе другое число: ";
            cin >> menu;

        } while (menu != 0);
        break;

    }
}
```

Comment: Я считаю, что тут проблема в том что для функции сокращения и подсчета нужно брать значение числителя и знаменателя, но не менять их самих. Только я не знаю как это сделать в sctruct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привёл в порядок вашу программу, исправил все ваши ошибки и подобавлял комментариев где что и как неправильно) Данная программа протестирована на всех возможных тестах!

```js
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
//нельзя добавлять библиотеку cmath!!!

using namespace std;

//Написать программу по вычеслению суммы ряда. Вычисления суммы ряда происходят накопление. Следуйщий элемент суммы ряда прибавляется к предыдущим элементам.

//Структура Дробь
struct drob {
public:
   int chis = 1; //Числитель (значение 2 элемента ряда)
   int znam = 6; // Знаменатель (значение 2 элемента ряда)
   int n = 1; // Количество элементов сумм ряда

   //Функция ввода кол. элементов суммы ряда
   int enter() {
      cin >> n;
      while (n <= 0) //Проверка на допустимость
      {
         cout << "Неверное значение! Введите заново." << endl;
         cin >> n;
      }

      cout << endl;
      return n;
   }

   //Первая сумма ряда
   void sum_frac1() {
      if (n >= 1) {
         chis = 1;
         znam = 6;
         cout << endl;
         display(chis, znam); //Вывод первой дроби
         cout << endl;
      }

      if (n >= 2) {
         chis = 1;
         znam = 3;
         cout << endl;
         display(chis, znam); //Вывод второй дроби
         cout << endl;
      }

      for (int i = 3; i <= n; ++i) {
         int ai = i; // нахожу следующую дробь
         int bi = (i + 1) * (i + 2); // в препода конечная формула неверная!!!

         cout << ai << " " << bi << endl;

         chis = chis * bi + znam * ai;
         znam = znam * bi; // тут znam = , а не chis = 

         if (i != n) {
            cout << endl;
            display(chis, znam); //Вывод дроби
            cout << endl;
         }
      }
   }

   //Вторая сумма ряда
   void sum_frac2() {
      if (n >= 1) {
         chis = 1;
         znam = 2;
         cout << endl;
         display(chis, znam); //Вывод первой дроби
         cout << endl;
      }

      if (n >= 2) {
         chis = 5;
         znam = 6;
         cout << endl;
         display(chis, znam); //Вывод второй дроби
         cout << endl;
      }

      int a1 = 1, b1 = 2;
      int a2 = 1, b2 = 3;

      for (int i = 3; i <= n; ++i) {
         int ai = a2 * a1 + b1 * b2; // нахожу следующую дробь
         int bi = b2 * a1;

         cout << ai << " " << bi << endl;

         chis = chis * bi + znam * ai;
         znam = znam * bi; // тут znam = , а не chis = 
         
         if (i != n) {
            cout << endl;
            display(chis, znam); //Вывод дроби
            cout << endl;
         }

         a1 = a2, b1 = b2; // подготовка к следующей итерации
         a2 = ai, b2 = bi;
      }
   }

   //Вывод дроби
   int display(int &chis, int &znam) {
      int l = 4;

      l = line(chis, znam); // длина линии
      cut_frac(chis, znam);

      ofstream file; //вывод конечного значения в файл
      //if (chis != znam) { для всех дробей
         file.open("C:\\Users\\Максуд\\Documents\\02.04.2021\\2 semester\\Проект4\\array.txt");
         cout << chis << endl;
         file << chis << endl;
         while (l > 0) {
            cout << "-";
            file << "-";
            l--;
         }
         cout << endl << znam;
         file << endl << znam;
      //}
      //else { // ?
      //   cout << chis;
      //   file << chis;
      //}

      file.close();
      return 0;
   }

private:

   //Сокращение дроби
   void cut_frac(int &chis, int &znam) { // раз передаёте по ссылке делаю void!
      int nod = NOD(chis, znam); // 

      chis /= nod;
      znam /= nod;
      // return chis; // один возврат в функции! но в данном случае не нужно(void function)!
      //return znam;
   }

   //Наибольший Общий Делитель для сокращения
   int NOD(int chis, int znam) { // забыли передать аргументы! иначе заменит те что глобально = плохо!
      while (chis > 0 && znam > 0) {
         if (chis > znam) {
            chis %= znam;
         }
         else {
            znam %= chis;
         }
      }

      return chis + znam;
   }

   //Функция подсчета цифр в числе для нужной длинны дробной черты
   int line(int chis, int znam) { // забыли передать аргументы!
      int l = 0;
      if (chis > znam) {
         while (chis > 0) {
            l++;
            chis = chis / 10;
         }
      }
      else {
         while (znam > 0) {
            l++;
            znam = znam / 10;
         }
      }
      return l;
   }
};

int main() {

   setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

   int menu;
   cout << "Лабораторная №4\nВыполнил студент ДИНРб-11 Бикеев Максуд Рубинович" << endl;
   cout << "1. Ряд дробей\n2. Ряд последовательностей\n\nВведите номер: ";
   cin >> menu;

   switch (menu) {
      case 1:
         do {
            drob frac1;

            cout << "\nВведите кол-во n элементов ряда суммы: ";
            frac1.enter();
            frac1.sum_frac1();

            cout << "\nКонечный результат: " << endl;
            frac1.display(frac1.chis, frac1.znam);

            cout << "\n\nЕсли хотите выйти то введите 0, иначе другое число: ";
            cin >> menu;

         } while (menu != 0);

         break;

      case 2:
         do {
            drob frac2;

            cout << "\nВведите кол-во n элементов ряда суммы: ";
            frac2.enter();
            frac2.sum_frac2();

            cout << "\nКонечный результат: " << endl;
            frac2.display(frac2.chis, frac2.znam);

            cout << "\n\nЕсли хотите выйти то введите 0, иначе другое число: ";
            cin >> menu;

         } while (menu != 0);
         break;

   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Простите, проще дать свой код (как-то писал для какого-то вопроса в ruSO). Вот код для первой задачи, работает до `n == 45`, потом начинается переполнение (https://ideone.com/eMVr8d). Для второй - приспособьте класс сами... Равно как и если вывод дроби не нравится.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <type_traits>

// НОД двух чисел
template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>>
    T gcd(T m, T n)
{
    while(m && n) if (m < n) n %= m; else m %= n;
    return m + n;
}

// НОК двух чисел    
template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>>
T lcm(T m, T n)
{
    return (m/gcd(m,n))*n;
}

class frac
{
public:
    frac(long long d, unsigned long long q = 1ull); // конструктор
    frac(const frac&)            = default;         // копирующий конструктор - устраивает сгенерированный
    frac& operator=(const frac&) = default;         // оператор присвоения - устраивает сгенерированный

    operator std::string() const;   // Приведение в строку


private:
    unsigned long long d, q;        // числитель и знаменатель
    int sign;                       // знак
    void norm();                    // функция нормализации (сокращения) дроби

    // арифметические операции
    friend frac operator +(const frac&a, const frac&b);
    friend frac operator -(const frac&a, const frac&b);
    friend frac operator *(const frac&a, const frac&b);
    friend frac operator /(const frac&a, const frac&b);

    friend bool operator ==(const frac&a, const frac&b);
    friend bool operator !=(const frac&a, const frac&b);

};

frac::frac(long long dd, unsigned long long qq)
{
    sign = (dd < 0) ? -1 : +1;
    d = dd*sign;
    q = qq;
    norm();
};

void frac::norm()
{
    unsigned long long g = gcd(d,q);
    if (g != 1) { d /= g; q /= g; }
}


frac operator +(const frac&a, const frac&b)
{
    long long dd;
    unsigned long long qq;
    if (a.q == b.q)
    {
        dd = a.d*a.sign + b.d*b.sign;
        qq = a.q;
    }
    else
    {
        qq = lcm(a.q,b.q);
        dd = a.d*a.sign*(qq/a.q) + b.d*b.sign*(qq/b.q);
    }
    return frac(dd,qq);
}

frac operator -(const frac&a, const frac&b)
{
    long long dd;
    unsigned long long qq;
    if (a.q == b.q)
    {
        dd = a.d*a.sign - b.d*b.sign;
        qq = a.q;
    }
    else
    {
        qq = lcm(a.q,b.q);
        dd = a.d*a.sign*(qq/a.q) - b.d*b.sign*(qq/b.q);
    }
    return frac(dd,qq);
}

frac operator *(const frac&a, const frac&b)
{
    return frac(a.d*a.sign*b.d*b.sign,a.q*b.q);
}

frac operator /(const frac&a, const frac&b)
{
    return frac(a.sign*b.sign*a.d*b.q,a.q*b.d);
}

bool operator ==(const frac&a, const frac&b)
{
    return a.d==b.d && a.q == b.q && a.sign == b.sign;
}

bool operator !=(const frac&a, const frac&b)
{
    return !(a==b);
}

frac::operator std::string() const
{
    std::string s = (sign > 0) ? "" : "-";
    s = s + std::to_string(d) + "/" + std::to_string(q);
    return s;
}


using namespace std;


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    frac f(0);
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        frac t(i-1,i*(i+1));
        f = f + t;
    }
    cout << string(f) << endl;
}
```

Да, `gcd` и `lcm` просто тогда не всходили в стандарт (или не были реализованы - не помню точно), так что если ваш компилятор их имеет - можете самопальные выбросить...

Comment: Согласен, лучше уже самому написать, но @Harry еще бы коментариев к коду добавить просто так с ходу не разберёшь новичку)

Comment: @GGO Ну... вроде все очевидно - арифметика дробей + нормализация при каждом чихе...

Comment: Когда я посмотрел на этот код я представил его как космический корабль... А потом посмотрел на свою карету... Если вас не затруднит не могли бы вы оставить краткий комментарий о назначении каждой функции?

Comment: Комментарии написал, а реализации арифметики - просто на бумажке расписываете, типа `a/b + c/d = (ad+bc)/ad` с последующей нормализацией...

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 2):

Ваша функция NOD модифицирует частное и делитель. Эту функцию нужно сделать константной и работать с копиями.

```
//Наибольший Общий Делитель для сокращения
int NOD()const
{
    int cchis = chis ;
    int cznam = znam ;
    while (cchis > 0 && cznam > 0)
    {
        if (cchis > cznam)
        {
            cchis %= cznam;
        }
        else
        {
            cznam %= cchis;
        }
    }

    return cchis + cznam;
}
```

*Функцию `line` точно так-же.*